# Necessary and sufficient conditions for $x'Ax = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, quadratic-forms

I came across the following problem and I am having a hard time thinking about it.

> Let $A$ be a $k\times k$ real matrix. Notice that I do not require that $A$ is symmetric, positive definite or anything else. I would like to consider any real matrix $A$ of such dimensions.
>
> Now, I am interested in necessary and sufficient conditions for $\exists x \neq 0$ such that $  x' A x = 0$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$.

Is this a known result? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that$$x^TAx = \sum_{i,j} A_{ij}x_i x_j = \sum_{i,j} 0.5(A_{ij}+A_{ji}) x_i x_j = 0.5x^T(A+A^T)x.$$
The second equality is due to each product $x_ix_j$ occuring twice in the summation when $i\neq j$. So the question is whether the symmetric matrix $A+A^T$ is positive definite.

Comment: If it's not positive definite, then we can apply some sort of continuity argument and find such $x$, right?

Comment: @RaulGuarini no continuity argument is needed, any eigenvector $x$ belonging to a nonpositive eigenvalue of $A+A^T$ will have $x^TAx \leq 0$.

Comment: True! Thanks a lot!